# iOS Use OpenCV to recognise a building

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, object-recognition

I'm wondering if it is possible to use the OpenCV framework to recognise a building? 
For example, if I store an image of a building, is it possible to use OpenCV to detect this building through the iPhone camera?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting known objects such as your building in an image can be done using the features2d module in OpenCV.

It works by detecting key points in the known image and computing a set of descriptors for these that can be compared to the key points and descriptors computed from the unknown scene image by a process known as matching.

The find_obj.py demo in the samples/python2 folder of OpenCV shows how to detect a known object in an image.

There is also a tutorial in the user guide, see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_features2d.html

Note that some of the algorithms often used (e.g. SURF and SIFT) are not free, and need to be licensed separately if you use them.

Answer (score 1):

Is possible, but, you have a long road to go. 
One way to do this: use visual keypoints to recognise objects.
[OpenCV Sift Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html)